# constexpr constructor with compile time validation

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'd like to build up a class with the option of constexpr-ness. And, of course, I'd like to take advantage of compile time error check.

Every `constexpr` function, constructor included, must work also at runtime, when the given parameters are not constant expression. That's should be the reason why every time you use `static_assert` in a `constexpr` function upon a function parameter it fails to compile.

Said so, I've read that one can use the exception throwing mechnanism, since when the function is called upon a constant expression, those exceptions can be evaluated at compile time. If that works, for functions the problem is solved.

But the problem is still not solved for constructors, since `constexpr` constructors seem to must have no body... so it looks like I can't use exception throwing from there!

Any idea?

Comment: You can use the comma operator. E.g: `widget::widget() : value_((throw some_exception(), 0)) { }`. Note that you don't have to use exceptions, it could be a call to a non-`constexpr` function also like `std::abort`.

Comment: ...or an `assert` works as well: `widget::widget(T t) : value_((assert(...), t)) {}`

Comment: @Casey `assert` is a macro that may well expand to an if-statement; beware of compile errors when moving to another compiler.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Per C99 (well, N1256 which is close) §7.2.1.1/2 "The `assert` macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; it expands to a `void` expression."

Comment: @Casey Ah, then I was wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following may help:

```
class A
{
public:
    constexpr A(int i) : i(i != 42 ? throw 42 : i) {}
private:
    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    constexpr A a1(42);
    //constexpr A a2(41); // Compile error as expected.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just got this error: 
`expression '<throw-expression>' is not a constant-expression`

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: Which compiler/version ?

Comment: mingw48, which comes with Qt 5.2.0 for Windows

Comment: It works for me with g++ TDD 4.7.1 and g++ TDD 4.8.1 (on windows too) . Yours seems to be gcc 4.8.0 . Cannot help more, sorry.

Comment: That's ok, I think this is the second c++11-related bug I found in mingw48... the first was with <regex>. Hope they'll fix