# Variadic Template of Templated Classes

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a struct, defined as follows:

```c++
template<typename T>
struct Variable
{
    char *name;

    constexpr Variable(char *setName) : name(setName)
    {

    }
};
```

I want to create a class whose template parameters are a list of those structs. So far, the closest I can get is this:

```
template<template<typename TF> Variable First, template<TA...> typename Variable ... Args>
class UniformBuffer
{
};
```

A UniformBuffer might be declared something like this:

```c++
// vec3 and vec4 are types defined elsewhere
UniformBuffer light<Variable<vec3>("location"), Variable<vec4>("rotation"), Variable<float>("intensity")>;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile, giving me the error "expected 'class' before 'Variable'" (though putting "class" in there simply generates another error, saying that it expected a '>' after 'Variable). Even looking at the various other amusingly-named questions about variadic templates, I don't seem to be able to find the answer for this. What is the correct syntax for what I am trying to do?

Comment: It should be `template<typename TF> class Variable`, not `template<typename TF> class Variable First`.

Comment: @remyabel but then how do I access First.name if I do that? I'm trying to make the template parameter a list of Variable<typename T>s.

Comment: Why do you want to have `Variable` as a template argument? Maybe you're looking for a constructor?

Comment: So you want a variadic template-template parameter? Or variadic list of non-type template parameters (with type `Variable<T>`)?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah, a constructor would probably work for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass objects of `Variable` as template parameters, because it cannot be deduced at compile time.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687553/4035785) is an answer which explains that

Comment: Is there no way to make it deducible at compile time through careful use of constexpr or something? It seems like if I type "Variable<int>("foo")", then that gives the compiler everything it needs.

Comment: But you are invoking here the constructor, and that cannot be done at compile time

Comment: C++11 doesn't have constexpr constructors? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557755/constexpr-constructor-with-compile-time-validation

Comment: Still it needs to allocate memory for the object

Comment: then I'm kind of confused as to the purpose of constexpr constructors.

Comment: Looks like it allows you tu use that object in constexpr functions. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#constexpr_.E2.80.93_Generalized_constant_expressions) you can read more about it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for a specialization:

```
template<typename First, typename... Args>
class UniformBuffer;

template<typename First, typename... Args>
class UniformBuffer<Variable<First>,Variable<Args>...>
{
};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6af023ced90d314)

Comment: I am not looking for a specialization. I am trying to make the template parameter for UniformBuffer a list of object Variable<anyTypeHere>.

Comment: @Avi: You **are** looking for a specialization, as this is exactly what will solve your problem. Try it!

Comment: @Avi It would also help to show the (possibly hypothetical) syntax you'd wish to work as a result.

Comment: @DanielFrey No, because I need to access the name of each of the template parameters as well.

Comment: @Avi I meant an example of *usage* of `UniformBuffer`. What we see now is only an invalid declaration.

Comment: @jrok Ah, okay, adding that now

Comment: @Avi: You have access to them, through `First` and `Args...` (or `Variable<First>` when you need that). What am I missing?

Comment: @DanielFrey I need access to the name property of the Variable class. The template parameters aren't supposed to be typenames, they're supposed to be Variables.

Comment: @Avi You pass the objects to `UniformBuffer`'s constructor.

Comment: @remyabel then don't I just have to figure out this same syntax, but put it before the constructor instead of the class declaration?

Comment: @remyabel or I guess it would work if I could recurse through variadic function parameters while recursing through variadic template parameters of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to pass class instances in as template arguments, since template arguments require compile time resolved things (like constants, function names, types).

<sub>It is unfortunate template arguments cannot be string literals.</sub>

What you can do is pass those instances into a helper function, from which you can generate a `tuple`-like object based on the types of those instances.

```
template <typename T>
struct Variable
{
    typedef T Type;
    const char *name;
    T val;
    constexpr Variable (const char *setName) : name(setName) {}
    operator T () const { return val; }
    operator T & () { return val; }
};

template <typename... V> UniformBuffer<V...> MakeUniformBuffer (V... args) {
    return UniformBuffer<V...>(args...);
}

{
    Variable<vec3> loc("location");
    Variable<vec4> rot("rotation");
    Variable<float> amp("intensity");
    auto ub = MakeUniformBuffer(loc, rot, amp);
...
}
```

The `MakeUniformBuffer` passes the instances into the constructor of `UniformBuffer`. `UniformBuffer` has to unpack the variable template arguments.

```
template <typename... V> class UniformBuffer;

template <typename V>
struct UniformBuffer <V> {
    V val;
    UniformBuffer(V v) : val(v) {}
...
};

template <typename V, typename... VV>
struct UniformBuffer<V, VV...> {
    V val;
    UniformBuffer<VV...> ub;
    UniformBuffer(V v, VV... rest) : val(v), ub(rest...) {}
...
};
```

It is possible to implement set and get methods on `UniformBuffer` to retrieve buffer elements by name. Below is an illustration of how to implement a get method:

```
template <typename V>
struct UniformBuffer <V> {
...
    typename V::Type get (const Variable<typename V::Type> &v) {
        if (v.name != val.name) throw v.name;
        return val;
    }
    template <typename R> R get (const Variable<R> &v) {
        throw v.name;
        return R();
    }
};

template <typename V, typename... VV>
struct UniformBuffer<V, VV...> {
...
    typename V::Type get (const Variable<typename V::Type> &v) {
        if (v.name != val.name) return ub.get(v);
        return val;
    }
    template <typename R> R get (const Variable<R> &v) {
        return ub.get(v);
    }
};

{
...
    auto ub = MakeUniformBuffer(loc, rot, amp);
    auto r = ub.get(rot);
...
}
```